# wide/double window shadows on Xubuntu 16.04 with Compton

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 16.04, compositing, compton

I installed Compton using [this tutorial](http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/) to reduce screen tearing on my Xubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately, there are strange shadows like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIPYL.png), but only around a few apps (for example Catfish or Gnomine). How to get rid of them? I've never had them before on Xubuntu 14.04 or Mint 17.

Comment: That picture looks like GNOME to me.

Comment: Yes, it's a random picture from the Internet, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Ah. Would it be any trouble to get a picture from your desktop though? That screenshot makes me think it's a theme issue.

Comment: Also, what graphics card do you have?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/RedvGoA.png

Comment: So the very first option in that config says it needs a stable graphics driver to use glx correctly. I'm thinking it could be that.

Comment: IMO it's not the theme issue, because I'm using the default one. I forgot to add that such strange shadows doesn't appear around every windows, but only around some apps.
My graphic cards are Intel HD 3000 + Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Robson CE [Radeon HD 6370M/7370M]

Comment: Ah, OK. Let's try this. Open the Additonal Drivers app by searching for it and select the `amdgpu` option.

Comment: There's no such a driver, I've already checked that. My graphic card is probably not supported by this driver. On 14.04 I had an option to use fglrx, but the open source driver were better in terms of stability and performance.

Comment: There should be a proprietary option there. Run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal and close and reopen the Additional Drivers app.

Comment: I tried and there's still no proprietary driver. Old AMD cards are not supported by proprietary drivers, are they?

Comment: That's not a very old card though, is it?

Comment: But try changing the `glx` option to `xrender`.

Comment: Oh, and 16.04 no longer uses fglrx. It's supposed to be amdgpu.

Comment: It's a five-year-old notebook. Changing to xrender doesn't help.

Comment: Here's the problem. Generic drivers usually do have screen tearing, and it isn't really something you can fix without a proprietary driver. That guide is most likely meant for people who have issues even with proprietary drivers. You could try downloading from AMD's site.

Comment: I've found the solution. This issue is relateg to gtk3.
https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/2qk7c3/with_i3_compton_and_gtk3_make_rounded_corners_on/cn6zjme

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with GTK 3. Here is the solution:
https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/2qk7c3/with_i3_compton_and_gtk3_make_rounded_corners_on/cn6zjme